# Can anyone tell me which book is cited?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

in the attached section from Peter Grindrod‘s book *Pattern and waves* from 1991, the authors refers to a book with the number [15] which contains some strong maximum principle for linear parabolic equations.

Unfortunately, I cannot see the Bibliography but maybe anyone can tell me which book he is citing with number [15]?

I would like to see the mentioned strong max. principle in that book.

Cheers!

[image: from Peter Grindrod: Patterns ans Waves, 1991]

Answer (score 1):

It's good to give a quick picture only answer.

[image: reference no 15]